# ASP.NET Visual Studio 2012 using existing SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to create an ASP.NET web application.  I tried using the Getting Starting with ASP.NET 4.5 Tutorial but it creates a simple local database and all queries are written directly in the code.  The database that I am accessing (SQL Server 2008) has fifteen complex stored procedures that I really don't want to have to retype.

Using the `DBContext` example in the tutorial works fine when just grabbing all of the data from the tables, but how do I use the stored procedures that are in the database?  Can someone please tell me the best way to use the stored procedures that already exist?

All of the questions (and answers) I've found so far are dealing with earlier versions of Visual Studio, and although I know that I could use these (since VS 2012 does support the backward compatibility), I want to make the best use of the software that I have and not use "best practices" from VS 2010.

If you can tell me how to use the existing stored procedures, or even direct me to a book, website, or anything else that would show this to me, I would TRULY appreciate it!  Happy coding!  And thanks for your time!

Comment: Searching for "sql server 2008 call stored procedure dbcontext" on Google returns a ton of links. Are you saying you couldn't find anything useful?

Comment: I tried using some of the examples like context.database.SQLQuery, but there is just not enough information there to follow (meaning it doesn't list all of the steps) because when I type context. (database is not an available option from the list).  I also tried using an IEnumerable example that I found, and it throws an Exception saying that DataReader does not contain all of the fields in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to piece together info from a few different sources, but I was able to get this working.  Here are my steps (I may have done more than I needed, but it worked) just in case it may help someone else:

1. Added a class to my project Called MyContext, and told it was a DBContext and pointed it to my existing database like this:  (Please note that I did already have the full Connection String in my webconfig file under .

   {
   public class MyContext : DbContext
   {
       public MyContext()
           : base("name=MyDatabase")
       {
       }
   }
   }

MyDatabase is replaced with the actual name that refers to my database in the connection string of my webconfig file.

1. I created a class called ProductList which exposes only the fields that are returned by my stored procedure:

   {
   public class ProductList
   {
       [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
       public int ProductID { get; set; }
       [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Model")]
       public string ProductName { get; set; }
   }

}

1. I actually created a user control (.ascx) which is a just a DataReapeater.  In the code-behind on the control, right beneather the Page_Load, I created a Method called GetMostPopular:

   public IEnumerable GetMostPopular()
       {
           var db = new MyContext();
         IEnumerable result = db.Database.SqlQuery("MostPopularProducts");
           return result;
       }

Inside the <> of IEnumerable and SQLQuery is the name of the Class I created.  It as the exact same fields that will be returned by my stored procedure "MostPopularProducts".

1. Then in the DataRepeater, I used GetMostPopular as the "SelectMethod":

   '><%# Eval("ProductName") %>

5.Then I just dragged and dropped the User Control onto the page where I wanted it to display.

I hope this helps someone else.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the SqlClient, SqlCommand, SqlConnection...
very easy, with organic output!